# Centering the row in Bootstrap with a minimum width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bit of a silly question regards bootstrap as I seem to have lost my mind today... anyway I wish to set the background colour of my `container-fluid` div so that it spans the full width of the page. However I wish for the child `row-fluid` div to sit in the middle of the parent with a minimum width of (for example: 970px). The `row-fluid` div will contain various `col-*` divs. This picture may help:

[image: Layout Image]

In my HTML I have the following structure:

```
   <div class="container-fluid text-center header">
       <div class="row"> <!-- when I use class="row-fluid" I lose the centering -->
            <div class="col-xs-3">Logo</div> <!-- i have used the col-md-* class too) -->
            <div class="col-xs-3">Dropdown</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">Telephone</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">Local</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my css ( notice I am using the text-center class provided by bootstrap)

```
.header .row {
  margin: auto;
  float: none;
  width: 970px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Now this works although I really want to use the responsive aspects of the Bootstrap Grid and when I resize the window the site isn't responsive. I know for this I should use the `row-fluid` class to achieve this but then I lose my centering effect. Perhaps I should use offsets, does anyone have an ideas how I can achieve what I want? I also realise that my code has 4 columns and my image has 3 cols. Thanks in advance. I am using Bootstrap 3.1.1

Comment: .col-xs- provides the most responsiveness

Comment: There is no `.row-fluid` class in bootstrap 3. And there are no `col-sm-3` in bootstrap 2.

Comment: Sorry will change my example to col-xs

Comment: And you need to specify a _relative_ width for your `.header .row`. Unless you provide that styling within a media query.

Answer (score 3):

use max-width 970px, width 100%, margin left auto and margin right auto for .header .row

that should cause the width to be 970px and center the div, it should also scale down as you decrease the viewport size

Comment: u deserve a beer!